# Icon click event inside bootstrap carousel not firing in Chrome but ok in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel with images. Inside each image I have a font awesome icon for a trash can in the upper right corner. In IE I can click and trigger the trash can event, but in Chrome and Edge it seems like the trash can is behind the carousel flippers. Why is it different in different browsers and how can I fix it so the trash can click event is fired in all browsers?

Here is my [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2wLz6xr/411/) and the code

```html
<div id="profile-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" style="width: 225px; height: 225px !important;">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    @if (hasImage) { for (int i = 0; i
    < imageCount; i++) { var isMainImage=M odel.ProfilePhotoViewModel.YogaProfileImages.ElementAt(i).IsMainImage; <div id=@Model.ProfilePhotoViewModel.YogaProfileImages.ElementAt(i).YogaProfileImageId class="item @(isMainImage == true ? "
      active " : " ") profile-image">
      <img class="img-responsive" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;" src="data:image/jpg;base64, @(Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ProfilePhotoViewModel.YogaProfileImages.ElementAt(i).ImageThumbnailCropped)))" alt="profile image">
      <i style="z-index: 200; position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px; color: whitesmoke;" class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x"></i>
      <i style="z-index: 200; position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 35px; color: yellow;" class="fa @(isMainImage == true ? " fa-star " : "fa-star-o ") fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
  } } else {
  <div class="item active profile-image">
    <img class="img-responsive" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 6px; border-image: none;" src="~/Images/no_image.jpg" alt="no profile image">
  </div>
  }

</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<a style="visibility: @visible; border-radius: 6px;" class="left carousel-control" href="#profile-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a style="visibility: @visible; border-radius: 6px;" class="right carousel-control " href="#profile-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle works identically in firefox, chrome and Edge ... so, if it behaves differently in IE, that the problem

Comment: I got 2 propositions for you, is it really necessary to position the trash icon at its current position? if not, then what we can do is to adjust the position of it. else, here is my other proposition, we can do something to the flippers of the slider, in which the "next image" function will be just fired upon clicked precisely to the chevron buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i already updated your fiddle, just add

```
top: auto; bottom: 50%;
```

for overwriting carousel-control class styling, like this

```
<a style="top: auto; bottom: 50%; visibility: visible; border-radius: 6px;" class="left carousel-control" href="#profile-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
```

check the update
http://jsfiddle.net/r2wLz6xr/412/